# How does MCT (Medium Chain Triglycerides) oil + caffeine biologically provoke accelerated entry into ketogenesis?

Tags: caffeine, fasting, ketosis, ketone, keto-adaption

Some years ago while experimenting with MCT oil and caffeine, I found that after a night's sleep and in a state of natural fasting (not eating for ~10 hours), I have been able to reliably enter into ketosis within 30 minutes after consuming a small amount of caffeine (around 50 mg) and drinking around a tablespoon of MCT oil.

What's the biological process that occurs to facilitate such a rapid entry into ketosis?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?

Comment: So far it has been a bit frustrating in that the keto topic has taken the world by storm in such a way as to make most of the search results superficial. I've briefly seen that MCT oil either emulates ketone bodies in some fashion or prompt the liver to begin ketogenesis, but, as noted, it's rather superficial. Eg, you see things like: "MCT oil goes straight to the liver and can be used for instant energy or converted to ketones."

Comment: So how do you know this isn't unique to you? Your only evidence that it has such properties is from a study with N = 1.

Comment: @CareyGregory first, I'm not asking about or due to uniqueness. If you notice my question I'm asking for the biological process that occurs. I'd like to understand this in detail. Secondly, I have seen repeated results results with 3 other family members and friends. It's clearly not isolated, but I would like to see more details of what goes on from someone who has intimate understanding of human biological processes since, while there appears to be some level of understanding, so much is now just static due to the keto marketing interjections.

Comment: My point is you're asking for an explanation of a biological process you haven't established exists (even with N=4 it's still just anecdotal). I found [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31689118/) in about 30 seconds. Your question would be greatly improved (and would quit attracting close votes) if it included something like that for background. It establishes that what you're asking about is real and not unique to you and your family members'.